# Thinkpad t440p wireless network controller

Tags: wireless, thinkpad, realtek

I have a Thinkpad T440P with Realtek 818b as wireless network controller. Is there any device driver available for this controller?

If there is not, which other Realtek WiFi network controllers are similar to this one, with source code, so that I can try to make one?

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:818b]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: ~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:818b]

Comment: I never had this problem anymore, because i have changed my network card to an intel one.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no device driver in Linux for this device. Please see here: http://wikidevi.com/wiki/Realtek_RTL8192EE_Reference_Design

> Linux driver probably not, at least, not yet

And the bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1239578
I suggest you register and add to the bug report.

If you have or can find a Windows XP driver, you may be able to get it going with ndiswrapper. ndiswrapper requires XP and will not work with Windows Vista, 7 or 8 driver files.

Answer (score 1):

I own a T440s, and I have the same problem.

I sent email to Realtek, but doubt if there would be any response.

The best solution now is to get a usb wireless adapter. It cost about $10, and can be used in other machines.